# Manually build a shared object using boost::python

Tags: python, c++, macos, boost-python

I'm trying to create a shared object using `boost::python` (installed through homebrew) that's loadable in Python on OS X using the Python 2.7 that ships with the OS. What libraries do I have to link in to get a usable shared object?

Here's `hello_ext.cpp`, taken from the tutorial

```
// hello_ext.cpp
char const* greet() {
  return "hello, world";
}

#include <boost/python.hpp>

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
  using namespace boost::python;
  def("greet", greet);
}
```

I can compile the example like this, although it takes a while.

```
$ clang++ -fPIC -c -I/usr/include/python2.7 hello_ext.cpp
```

However, when I attempt to link it and produce an `so` I get a bunch of undefined symbols:

```
$ clang++ -shared -o hello_ext.so hello_ext.o | & head -n 7
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyString_Type", referenced from:
      boost::python::to_python_value<char const* const&>::get_pytype() const in hello_ext.o
  "__Py_NoneStruct", referenced from:
      boost::python::api::object::object() in hello_ext.o
  "boost::python::detail::init_module(char const*, void (*)())", referenced from:
      _inithello_ext in hello_ext.o
```

Some of them clearly come from the Python interpreter, and indeed `-lpython` solves some of the unresolved symbol errors:

```
$ clang++ -shared -o hello_ext.so hello_ext.o -lpython | & head -n 7
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::python::detail::init_module(char const*, void (*)())", referenced from:
      _inithello_ext in hello_ext.o
  "boost::python::detail::gcc_demangle(char const*)", referenced from:
      boost::python::type_info::name() const in hello_ext.o
  "boost::python::detail::scope_setattr_doc(char const*, boost::python::api::object const&, char const*)", referenced from:
      void boost::python::def<char const* (*)()>(char const*, char const* (*)()) in hello_ext.o
```

The documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/python/doc/html/building.html) for `boost::python` goes into some detail about how to use the library in conjunction with `cmake`, but doesn't say much about what libraries are required at link time.

Comment: You need to link with the boost_python library, normally that would be libboost_python\* or libboost_python3\* depending on whether you want python2 or python3 (the exact name is system-dependent).

Comment: `brew` does not seem to have installed a library with that name as part of the `boost` package itself, although the headers are included in the `boost` package. `libboost_python.{a,dylib}` does appear to be part of `boost-python`.

Comment: Headers are not enough for boost::python, you need binary libraries. Your installation is either broken or uses unusual names for libraries. Or perhaps you are supposed to build them yourself (check if there is a large bunch of .cpp files that came with the installation).

Comment: That isn't what I meant. The `brew` package labeled `boost` and `boost-python` to appear to overlap slightly ... `boost-python` does contain the headers and object files.

Comment: Aw sorry didn't see it (it's kinda hard to read on the phone). So you probably need to link with one of these libraries.

Comment: Sorry, thank you for answering. Your recommendation worked and `clang++ -shared -o hello_ext.so hello_ext.o -lpython -lboost_python` produced a loadable native Python module. If I could accept your comment I would.

Comment: I shall write a proper answer when I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::python` is not a header-only library, it includes a binary component. You need to link with it, for example

```
clang++ ... -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lboost_python -lpython2.7
```

The library is apparently installed by the homebrew package `boost-python`, not `boost`.